# Eclipse FAILS to preserve project Configuration settings in CDT

Tags: configuration, eclipse-cdt, symbols, project-settings

I am working with Neon Eclipse. I have a number of `#ifdefs` in the project that I am working on, that require *Project Settings* to set up the Symbols for numerous configuration options, and those configurations will change based on which system I am testing or developing on. I created a new Configuration for the device that I am working on, and set a number of these for that particular configuration, and set that configuration as the ACTIVE configuration. Eclipse has a nasty habit of crashing frequently, and when I restart it, the configuration that I created, fails to be displayed. I can see all of those symbols, in my .cproject file as shown:

```
<storageModule moduleId="cdtBuildSystem" version="4.0.0">
    <configuration buildProperties="" description="" id="cdt.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.cross.base.2114774863" name="Default" optionalBuildProperties="" parent="org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.emptycfg">
        <folderInfo id="cdt.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.cross.base.2114774863.724359072" name="/" resourcePath="">
            <toolChain id="cdt.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.cross.base.1348139852" name="Cross GCC" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.cross.base">
                <option id="cdt.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.prefix.570851752" name="Prefix" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.prefix"/>
                <option id="cdt.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.path.1106293179" name="Path" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.path"/>
                <targetPlatform archList="all" binaryParser="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ELF" id="cdt.managedbuild.targetPlatform.gnu.cross.753093604" isAbstract="false" osList="all" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.targetPlatform.gnu.cross"/>
                <builder id="cdt.managedbuild.builder.gnu.cross.899937427" keepEnvironmentInBuildfile="false" managedBuildOn="false" name="Gnu Make Builder" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.builder.gnu.cross"/>
                <tool id="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.c.compiler.156043221" name="Cross GCC Compiler" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.c.compiler">
                    <option IS_BUILTIN_EMPTY="false" IS_VALUE_EMPTY="false" id="gnu.c.compiler.option.preprocessor.def.symbols.1327001072" name="Defined symbols (-D)" superClass="gnu.c.compiler.option.preprocessor.def.symbols" useByScannerDiscovery="false" valueType="definedSymbols">    
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="CONFIG_MOTOPIA_DOCKER"/>    
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="STANDALONE"/>   
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="CONFIG_MOTOPIA_WL80211_MULTIRADIO"/>    
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="CONFIG_MOTOPIA_DEFAULT_VALS"/>  
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="CONFIG_MOTOPIA_IPV6"/>
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="CONFIG_MOTOPIA_LHD"/>
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="CONFIG_MOTOPIA_MOCA"/>
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="CONFIG_MOTOPIA_BRIDGEMODE"/>
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="CONFIG_MOTOPIA_HTTPS"/>
                        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="CONFIG_MOTOPIA_LANMGMT"/>
                    </option>
                    <inputType id="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.c.compiler.input.711910598" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.c.compiler.input"/>
                </tool>
```

However, I am not seeing the name of the Configuration that I created and set as Active. Why is Eclipse doing this, and what can I do to make it behave properly?

Comment: (I tried to improve readability of the config: it looks incomplete.) `Eclipse has a nasty habit of crashing frequently` I hear you. Doesn't resemble my memory of Eclipse Neon (PDT&JDT on MS W7 Home).

Comment: It's a very long file. It exceeds the limit of the number of allowable characters.